# Module redirecting back to wrong site after submit button pressed

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, module, base-url

I am using Moogento's shipEasy module for order processing and after changing my base URL (admin.sconch.com) to be different to my main website's URL (www.sconch.com) there seems to be a small bug in that after pressing the submit button to carry out an action from the dropdown menu at the top of the page it tries to redirect back to www.sconch.com/admin/... rather than remaining on admin.sconch.com/admin/....

I think that I have traced the error back to this code in **/app/code/local/Moogento/ShipEasy/Helper/Grid.php:**

```
protected function _getUrl($route, $params = array())
{
return Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl($route, $params);
}
```

changing this to:

```
protected function _getUrl($route, $params = array())
{
return Mage::getBaseUrl();
}
```

returns to the frontend admin.sconch.com but does not process the requested action.

Can anyone tell me what code I should use to return to the correct admin.sconch.com/admin/... page with the changes applied?

Thanks,

Hugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually seems to be a Magento bug: http://www.magthemes.com/magento-blog/magento-142-multiwebsite-admin-redirect-problem-quick-workaround

I would have thought that given this was identified in 1.4 it would have been fixed by 1.9 but the workaround in the linked blog post prevents my error (albeit it doesn't actually solve the underlying bug).

If anyone can see how to actually fix the underlying bug in Magento that would be cool!

Thanks,

Hugh